# JAVA incompatible type value

Tags: java

Hello stackoverflow community. I need help, I'm new in JAVA. I've created this:

```
public static Modulis[] surasti_visus (Modulis G[], int n, int minimalus) {
    Modulis X[] = new Modulis[n];
    Modulis min = minimalus;
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(min.gautiKreditus() < G[i].gautiKreditus()) X[i] = G[i];
    return X;
}
```

In order to find all bigger values then minimalus and write them to new array. But i get error because of this line:

```
Modulis min = minimalus;
```

Eror is: incompatible types; required Modulis; found int;
What is wrong here please help!

Comment: `minimalus` is of type `int`.  `min` is of type `Modulis[]`.  You can only assign a value of type `Modulis` to a variable that is declared as that type.  Is there a way to make a `Modulis` out of an `int`?  Perhaps a constructor that takes an `int` parameter?  Or did you mean to just say `if (min < G[i].gautiKreditus())`?

Comment: @soong yea i mean if (min < G[i].gautiKreditus())

Answer (score 3):

Problem: you try to save int value to Modulis type, it's impossible in Java, you need use

```
public static Modulis[] surasti_visus (Modulis G[], int n, Modulis minimalus) {
    Modulis X[] = new Modulis[n];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(minimalus.gautiKreditus() < G[i].gautiKreditus()) X[i] = G[i];
    return X;
}
```

or

```
public static Modulis[] surasti_visus (Modulis G[], int n, int minimalus) {
    Modulis X[] = new Modulis[n];
    Modulis min = new Modulis(minimalus);
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(min.gautiKreditus() < G[i].gautiKreditus()) X[i] = G[i];
    return X;
}
```

or

```
public static Modulis[] surasti_visus (Modulis G[], int n, int minimalus) {
    Modulis X[] = new Modulis[n];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(minimalus < G[i].gautiKreditus()) X[i] = G[i];
    return X;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, I'm guessing that `Modulis.gautiKreditus()` returns an `int`, which you meant to compare with the `min` value.  As such, just declare `min` as an int (or don't declare it at all, as you're just using the value passed in):

```
public static Modulis[] surasti_visus (Modulis G[], int n, int minimalus) {
    Modulis X[] = new Modulis[n];
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        if(minimalus < G[i].gautiKreditus()) X[i] = G[i];
    return X;
}
```

Now you're comparing `int`'s to `int`'s, and there's no need to put the minimum value into another variable.